# mysql select when matching multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a project where I need to select only the users that answered to some questions in a certain way (based on a filter).

The **filter table** (filter) looks like this

```
   question |   answer  

   Q1       |    A  
   Q2       |    B
```

The **user table** (answers) looks like this

```
user | question | answer  

  1  |    Q1    |    A  
  1  |    Q2    |    D  
  2  |    Q1    |    A  
  2  |    Q2    |    B
```

How can I select from the user table only the user(s) that match the filter?
I tried

```
"SELECT user FROM answers WHERE (question = Q1 AND answer = A) 
             AND (question = Q2 AND answer = B)"
```

and it doesn't work -- I get an empty result. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
select answers.user
from filter, answers
where filter.question=answers.question and filter.answer=answers.answer
group by answers.user having count(answers.question)=2
```

or

```
select user
from answers
where user not in 
(select distinct a.user from answers a, filter f 
where a.question=f.question and a.answer!=f.answer)
```

Comment: Both your solutions work. Great job and thanks for taking the time. I  have now to see which solution is the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

In your query you are asking to get data which is not present. You are trying to get that user which has both the combination.

Try this

```
SELECT user FROM answers WHERE (question = 'Q1' AND answer = 'A') 
         OR (question = 'Q2' AND answer = 'B')
```

Comment: Yes, it is present. I need the user that answered A to Q1 and B to Q2, to match the filter. What you are proposing will look only for one question/answer pair and not for both.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select 
DISTINCT(userId)
from user_table ut
inner join filtertable ft on (ut.question=ft.question and ut.answer=ft.answer)
```

Comment: I was going to write almost the same query with the same join conditions, but the OP only wanted to select answer.user.

Comment: To do that he needs select distinct id

Comment: It doesn't work. I get both users and I should get only user 2, because only user 2 completely matches the filter.